# Serializing XML to file

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have the following class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Super
{

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "V")]
    public class V
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "value2")]
        public string Value2 { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "L")]
    public class L
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "item")]
        public string item { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "upc")]
        public string Upc { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "decimals")]
        public string decimals { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "prod")]
        public string Prod { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Cclass")]
        public string Cclass { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "P_B")]
    public class P_B
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "pb")]
        public string pb { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "udf_value")]
        public string Udf_value { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "W")]
    public class W
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "P_B")]
        public List<P_B> P_B { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "P_PRICE")]
    public class P_PRICE
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lvl")]
        public string lvl { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "price")]
        public string Price { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "A_req")]
        public string A_req { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "season")]
        public string Season { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "season")]
        public string season { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "P_R")]
    public class P_R
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "P_PRICE")]
        public P_PRICE P_PRICE { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "P_A")]
    public class P_A
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "store")]
        public string Store { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "A")]
        public string A { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "m")]
        public string M { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ma")]
        public string Ma { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "transfer")]
        public string Transfer { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Oout")]
        public string Oout { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "P_AS")]
    public class P_AS
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "P_A")]
        public List<P_A> P_A { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "P_T")]
    public class P_T
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "came_from")]
        public string Came_from { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "P")]
    public class P
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "W")]
        public W W { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "P_YY")]
        public string P_YY { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "P_R")]
        public P_R P_R { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "P_AS")]
        public P_AS P_AS { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "P_T")]
        public P_T P_T { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "D")]
        public string D { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "P_G")]
        public string P_G { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "no")]
        public string no { get; set; }

    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "XY")]
    public class XY
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "V")]
        public V V { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "L")]
        public L L { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "P")]
        public P P { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ITEMS")]
    public class ITEMS
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "XY")]
        public List<XY> XY { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "SETUP")]
    public class SETUP
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ITEMS")]
        public ITEMS ITEMS { get; set; }
    }



}
```

I'm trying to serialize this data with:

```
SETUP f = new SETUP();
f.ITEMS.XY = new List<XY>();

    using(var stream = new FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\file.xml", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    XmlSerializer X = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SETUP));
                    X.Serialize(stream, X);
                }
```

However it is giving an error, I have tried other variations however still unsuccessful.

I have googled and seen multiple stackoverflow posts but I can't seem to get this to write to a file with that I give.

The error I'm getting is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer'
>   to type 'tool.SETUP'.

Like pointed out I should've used "f" not X I changed it so much I lost track of that however now when I try to serialize I get:

```
SETUP f = new SETUP(); ITEMS x = new ITEMS(); List<XY> u = new List<XY>(); u.Add(new XY() { });
```

Is not proper usage I'm getting an error, basically i can't set the values..i'm going based off of an example on stackoverflow –

"Has some invalid arguments" is the exact error

If I simplify the classes A LOT it works if there are only a few elements but since there are nested elements this might be causing an issue? Is it not possibly to instantiate this level of xml?

Comment: Are you sure about this: `X.Serialize(stream, X);`  Where do you want to use `f`  :)

Comment: oh my god...it should be f....

Comment: SETUP f = new SETUP();
            ITEMS x = new ITEMS();
            List<XY> u = new List<XY>();
            u.Add(new XY() { });

Is not proper usage I'm getting an error, basically i can't set the values..i'm going based off of an example on stackoverflow

Comment: You should edit the question and not putting updates as comments :)

Comment: `I'm getting an error, basically i can't set the values.` Don't share that much info when asking. People can abuse it :)

Comment: @Eser I made it more specific :) sorry

Comment: Are you getting any compiler errors?  "out" is a reserved word and cannot be used as a variable name : public string out { get; set; }

Comment: @jdweng sorry I made a Typo it should just read Oout I changed the post. No compiling error. I'm not sure how to instantiate the class to set the values

Comment: You can't use class as a variable name : public string class { get; set; }  Try : public string _class { get; set; }

Comment: @jdweng Cclass should be what it is, i modified the post thanks, but still unable to set the values...XY is a list so when I try the add(new XY(){ THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS}) still can not set values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Super.SETUP super = new Super.SETUP() {
                ITEMS = new Super.ITEMS() {
                    XY = new List<Super.XY>() {
                       new Super.XY() { L = new Super.L() { Cclass = "ABC"}}
                   }
                }
            };


            using (var stream = new FileStream(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\file.xml", FileMode.Create))
            {
                XmlSerializer X = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Super.SETUP));
                X.Serialize(stream, super);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This did the trick...this helped me understand serializing xmls...the other examples were easy this one threw me off a bit but this is awesome! Thanks!!!!